# AWS Glue change schema from json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I want to change AWS Glue table schema based on a JSON file.
The JSON is in the format `{"column_name0":"data_type0","column_name1":"data_type1"}`.
How can I do that? I've read that it is possible to use a [JSON classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Classifier.html) but I don't know how. I've tried adding my JSON file inside the S3 folder where the file from which the crawler creates the table is stored but it creates another table from the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an odd choice to do this, do you have a specific scenario in mind that requires you to create schema by hand? Using either a crawler with a [from_catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog), or a [from_options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create_dynamic_frame_from_options) directly on a source will generally infer the schema quite well. If there are limited columns you want to keep, just select those columns from your frame and discard the rest. If you have specific needs to transform (e.g. cast) the data types, use [ResolveChoice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html).

That being said, there are a few options available to you:

- If you are deploying via CDK, you could specify the schema for the a [glue table within a glue DB via your CDK code, in the columns option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-glue.Table.html) (which you could programmatically create from your file)
- If you are deploying via CLI, you could create a simple script (e.g. in powershell or bash) that creates a properly formatted table input for CLI based on your JSON file, and invoke the [create table command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/create-table.html)

Note: I don't expect that a JSON classifier will work for you here. You could use a [custom classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json), but that will only allow you to specify the columns (by JSONPath) that you would like to use, and the types would be inferred. You would need to edit that custom classifier each time you wanted to change the schema as well.

Comment: Actually I thought it was the easiest way. Apparently it's not! In my case the infer schema is not good, but I have more than 200 columns so change them from edit schema directly in the table is not feasible.  I will try using the crawler options